# How do I store multiple text boxes?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am creating a form in Google App Script to create multiple events at once, I have methods to create another event text box and then add it to the panel but I don't know how to create the multiple events. How should I store the multiple text boxes so that I can call createEvent() on each of them?

```
function doGet(){

 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QuickAdd Events');

 //Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
 var parent = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('parent');
 var left = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('left').setWidth(200);
 var right = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('right');

 var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
 var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle').setWidth(200);
 var eventButton = app.createButton('Create Events');
 var childButton = app.createButton('+ Event');

 left.add(eventTitleLabel)
     .add(eventTitle);  

 right.add(eventButton)
      .add(childButton);

 var eventHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
 eventHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
 eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler);

 var panelHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createAnotherEvent');
 panelHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
 childButton.addClickHandler(panelHandler);

 parent.add(left)
       .add(right);

 app.add(parent);
 app.close();
 return app;
}

function createAnotherEvent(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
 var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle').setWidth(200);

 app.getElementById('left').add(eventTitleLabel)
                           .add(eventTitle);
 return app;
}

function createEvents(e){

 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
try{
 //get the entries;
 var event = e.parameter.eventTitle;

 var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
 cal.createEventFromDescription(event);

 app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));

 //make the form panel invisible
 app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);
 return app;
 }

//If an error occurs, show it on the panel
catch(e){
  app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+e));
  return app;
 }
}
```

Comment: Will the number of event be variable or fixed?  Do you know how many event /textboxes / buttons there will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a bit with your code but since I don't know exactly what you want to do I'm not sure it will help...

At least it shows how to know which button was pressed, how to create widgets in loops and assign them names and ids... but the whole thing is a bit messy I admit ;-)

feel free to destroy what you don't need.

```
function doGet(){

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QuickAdd Events');
  var label = ['label title1','label title2','label title3','label title4']
  var title = ['title1','title2','title3','title4']
  //Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
  var parent = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('parent');
  var left = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('left').setWidth(200);
  var right = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('right');
  var eventHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
  eventHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
  var panelHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createAnotherEvent');
  panelHandler.addCallbackElement(left);

  for(var n in label){
  var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel(label[n]);
  var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName(title[n]).setWidth(200);
  var eventButton = app.createButton('Create Events').setId('event'+n);
  var childButton = app.createButton('+ Event').setId('ch'+n);

  left.add(eventTitleLabel)
  .add(eventTitle);  

  right.add(eventButton)
  .add(childButton);

  eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler);

  childButton.addClickHandler(panelHandler);
  }  
  parent.add(left)
  .add(right);
  var hidden = app.createHidden('numberOfTitles').setId('numberOfTitles').setValue(n);// the number of events
  left.add(hidden);
  app.add(parent);
  app.close();
  return app;
}


function createAnotherEvent(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var source = Number(e.parameter.source.replace(/\D/g,''));// the event number from the button pressed
  var numberOfTitles = Number(e.parameter.numberOfTitles);
  numberOfTitles++
    app.getElementById('numberOfTitles').setValue(numberOfTitles);
  var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
  var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle'+numberOfTitles).setWidth(200);// this way the new textBow has a new predictable name and you can easily get it in the handler

  app.getElementById('left').add(eventTitleLabel)
  .add(eventTitle);
  return app;
}

function createEvents(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var source = Number(e.parameter.source.replace(/\D/g,''));
  var numberOfTitles = Number(e.parameter.numberOfTitles);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  try{
    //get the entries;
    var event = e.parameter.eventTitle;

    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    cal.createEventFromDescription(event);

    app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));

    //make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);
    return app;
  }

  //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
  catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+e));
    return app;
  }
}
```

EDIT : your script makes me think about an old post I answered a while ago, It might interrest you to have a look at it here : [Store & retrieve the identifiers of a multipliable widget's instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034174/store-retrieve-the-identifiers-of-a-multipliable-widgets-instances/12034415#12034415)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that. The main aim for this script is to have a label and text box paired to capture an event. There will only ever be two buttons, the "Create Event" button is to create all the events on the text boxes and the "+ Event" is to add another text box that will hold the event information.

I will have a look through your version of my code and see if I can adapt it to what I want. Thanks again :)

Comment: I have edited the above code so that it creates just one label and text box when it opens. When I try and use the incremented names for the create Event method it won't recognise the names, this is inside the create event method:

`for (var i = 0; i < numberOfEvents; i++){`

`var event = e.parameter.eventTitle+i;`
`var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();`
`cal.createEventFromDescription(event);`
`app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));`
`}`
`app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);`
`return app;`
`}`

Comment: you have to use a slightly different syntax : e.parameter[eventTitle+i];

Comment: Sorry to pester you, but in the create event method the parameter that holds the hidden value can't be read. The hidden value is declared like this:
`var hidden =` `app.createHidden('noOfEvents').setId('noOfEvents').setValue(1);`

In the create event method this line is causing the error:
`var numberOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents);`

Comment: no worries ;) 2 things to check : 1: is the hidden widget added to the panel that is used as a callBackElement correctly ?  2: use the logger to check e (using  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) in the handler function, you will see if the value of hidden is in there... As a general rule, use the logger to check the important values all along, it helps a lot while debugging.  What you could also do to make thing easier is to replace the hidden widget with a textBox so that you actually "see" its value when you test the code and when you're done just set it invisible using .setVisible(false);

Comment: I wish there was a like button, you are a life saver. I don't even have a high enough reputation to "Vote Up" the answer. Thank you so much

Comment: such a nice comment is quite sufficient as a reward :)

Comment: What does the Source variable do in both the methods? They gave an error when I tried to use the code you supplied. They are also not used in the rest of the methods, well I can't see where source is used.

Comment: e.parameter.source returns the ID of the widget that triggers the handler. The replace  I added deletes any non decimal characters to keep only numbers and 'number' makes a number from this string. but since it appears you have only one button it becomes quite useless I guess...

Comment: I am going to ask a new question, to show my code and hopefully see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I am confused, where is source used in the code? Why does the ID of the widget need to be returned?